# how to load the modules in angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

I have a very big doubt. What is the way to call or load the modules?

Considering that I have 3 modules (module1, module2, module3), which will later have their own components and routes

in the routes (lazy loading)?
[image]

or import it into the component?

[image]

Maybe they are different things, I hope they can clarify for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To lazy load a module you would configure the routes as below.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'module1',
    loadChildren: () => import('./module1/module1.module').then(m => m.Module1Module)
  },
  {
    path: 'module2',
    loadChildren: () => import('./module2/module2.module').then(m => m.Module2Module)
  }
];
```